# Pandas Groubpy plotting with unstack()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'type':['john','bill','john','bill','bill','bill','bill','john','john'],
'num':[1006,1004,1006,1004,1006,1006,1006,1004,1004],
'date':[2017,2016,2015,2017,2017,2013,2012,2013,2012],
'pos':[0,0,1,4,0,3,3,8,9],
'force':[5,2,7,10,6,12,4,7,8]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

grp=df.sort_values('date').groupby(['type'])

for name, group in grp :
    print(name)
    print(group)
    group.plot(x='date', y='force', label=name)

plt.show()
```

The result obtained is as follows:

```
bill
   type   num  date  pos  force
6  bill  1006  2012    3      4
5  bill  1006  2013    3     12
1  bill  1004  2016    0      2
3  bill  1004  2017    4     10
4  bill  1006  2017    0      6
john
   type   num  date  pos  force
8  john  1004  2012    9      8
7  john  1004  2013    8      7
2  john  1006  2015    1      7
0  john  1006  2017    0      5
```

[img1_force_Bill][1]
[img2_Force_john][2]

how can i get 4 Fig, in each one 2 lines:

- Fig1 for bill: `line1(x=date , y= force)` for `num(1004)`/
  `line2(x=date , y= force)` for `num(1006)`
- Fig2 for bill: `line1(x=date , y= pos)` for `num(1004)`/
  `line2(x=date , y= pos)` for `num(1006)`
- Fig3 for john: `line1(x=date , y= force)` for `num(1004)`/
  `line2(x=date , y= force)` for `num(1006)`
- Fig4 for john: `line1(x=date , y= pos)` for `num(1004)`/
  `line2(x=date , y= pos)` for `num(1006)`

Comment: [Please read how to add image](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'type':['john','bill','john','bill','bill','bill','bill','john','john'],
'num':[1006,1004,1006,1004,1006,1006,1006,1004,1004],
'date':[2017,2016,2015,2017,2017,2013,2012,2013,2012],
'pos':[0,0,1,4,0,3,3,8,9],
'force':[5,2,7,10,6,12,4,7,8]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
axi=iter(ax.flatten())

grp=df.sort_values('date').groupby(['type'])
for name, group in grp :
#     print(name)
#     print(group)
    group.set_index(['date','num'])['force'].unstack().plot(title=name+' - force', ax=next(axi), legend=False)
    group.set_index(['date','num'])['pos'].unstack().plot(title=name+ ' - pos', ax=next(axi), legend=False)
    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0, -.5), ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

#### Update per comment below:

```
dfj = df[df['type'] == 'john']
ax = dfj.set_index(['date','num'])['force'].unstack().plot(title=name+' - force', legend=False)
ax.axhline(y=dfj['force'].max(), color='red', alpha=.8)
```

Chart:
[image]

Comment: thank you alot for your answer, is tt possible to add also max/min value as lines to each fig

Comment: @user13931873... Yes.  what values would you like in each... I will attenpt to modify the answer.

Comment: i would like to plot (x= max value of force ,y= date) of bill-force...(x= max value of force ,y= date) of john-force.......(x= max value of pos ,y= date) of bill-pos...(x= max value of pos,y= date) of john-pos

Comment: i would really thank you for your help, i appreciate that, but what i mean the force max value of both the line . so i expected ... Fig1 for bill: line1(x=date , y= force) for num(1004)/ line2(x=date , y= force) for num(1006) / line 3 (x=date , y=max force of 1004 and 1004) which shoud be a horizontal line.......and another question could you please plot it without subplot.

Comment: @user13931873 I am sort of confused.  But I will attempt another update.

Answer (score 0):

@[Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston)
.... thank you alot for your help.
unfortunately after using the following code with big data to plot 2 lines

```
for name, group in grp_new:
    axn= group.set_index(['date', 'num'])['pos'].unstack().plot(title= name+' _pos', legend=False)
```

the plot looks like [plot2Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zuD3.png) .They are not continuous plots.I tried to plot single lines and it were ok.

Comment: What do you wnat to do with missing data?  Zero or fill with the last known measurement?  Try `group.set_index(['date', 'num'])['pos'].unstack().ffill().plot(title= name+' _pos', legend=False)`